# Непонятный код в Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Есть код:

```
<link href="{{ elixir("css/material-dashboard.css") }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Я понимаю что, что он соединяет  компилированные стили но что значит функция `elixir()`, почему не использовать просто `asset()`?

Какую дополнительную пользу дает использование функции `elixir()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elixir()` нужен для `CSS` с увеличенным уровнем абстракции.

Многие программисты, когда занимаются дизайном, используют `SASS`, `LESS` и т.д.

Это такие штучки в которых `CSS` выглядит более удобно.

Ну например:

**SASS:**

```
.div {
    a {
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.div a {
    color: #000;
}
```

---

**SASS:**

```
%my-div-style {
  color: #000;
}

.div1 {
  @extend %my-div-style;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.div2 {
  @extend %my-div-style;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.div1, .div2 {
    color: #000;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

---

Понятное дело что чистый `SASS` в `.css` не положишь, потому что он не соответствует синтаксису `CSS`. Поэтому нужен тот, кто займется переделыванием `SAAS --> CSS`. И как можно понять, такого козлика нашли :)

Т.е. программист занимающийся дизайном пишет на `SASS`, а потом через `elixir()` все это дело переделывается в `CSS`.

---

После того как скомпилировался `CSS`, у него название стало другое. Был `test.sass` потом стал `test-hash.css`. Вот чтоб название сохранить используется `{{ elixir('test.sass') }}`.

`elixir` - изменяет файлы и создаешь их кеш.

Если вы используете `elixir` для `.css` перед этим не вызвав `elixir(function()){}` то конечно разницы с `asset()` не будет. Но если вы сделаете например:

```
elixir(function(mix) { // Пример из документации
  mix.version(['css/all.css']);
});
```

То тут уже разница в результате будет, потом что `elixir` создаст для этого файла кеш, будет другой путь и он вам его выдаст

Задача `asset()` - формировать корректный путь.
Задача `elixir()` - обработать, создать кеш, и выдать корректный путь к этому кешу.

Comment: Назначение Elixir- а  я знаю, для компиляции используется  **gulpfile.js** ,  вопрос был про helper   функцию elixir ( )    в частности про  непонятный код **<link href="{{ elixir("css/material-dashboard.css") }}" rel="stylesheet" />**  зачем соединять ссылку на  стили  с helper  функцией  **elixir( )** если есть  helper  функция  **asset( )** ;

Comment: @a_mine добавил в конец овтета

Comment: Elixir это тот же Laravel mix или mix это более новый вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Читайте документацию: [Elixir](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/elixir)

elixir может выполнять gulp-задачи. Преобразовывает пути в абсолютные.
asset только преобразовывает путь из относительного в абсолютный.

В Вашем варианте как раз ничего не соединяется.

Comment: Если возможно объясните более доходчиво какую дополнительную пользу дает использование функции elixir()?